# Giving up searching valid MPEG header after 65536 bytes of junk

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, mpeg, mpg123

I'm running some videos on a headless Raspberrypi using OMXPlayer. However, there is quite a gap when loading the video so I wanted to try out `mpg123` which is supposed to be quite fast.

I used VLC to convert my m4v video to an MPG format. However when I want to play the file I do consistently get the following error:

```
[src/libmpg123/parse.c:1204] error: Giving up searching valid MPEG header after 65536 bytes of junk.
```

In order to further debug the issue I tried an mpg file from the internet:

I'm using the `mpg123 version 1.23.8`.

My Pi:

```
 uname -a
 Linux raspi 4.19.66+ #1253 Thu Aug 15 11:37:30 BST 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Log

```
pi@raspi:~/button $ wget https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mpg/sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mpg
pi@raspi:~/Button $ mv sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mpg ocean.mpg

    $ mpg123 -vvv ocean.mpg
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
    version 1.23.8; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
    free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes
Decoder: generic
Trying output module: alsa, device: <nil>
Using default module dir: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mpg123
Module dir: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mpg123
Module path: ./output_alsa.so
Chosen output module: alsa

playlist in normal order:
ocean.mpg

Note: Disabling all formats.
Note: output support for 8000 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 8000/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 8000 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 8000/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 11025 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 11025/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 11025 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 11025/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 12000 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 12000/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 12000 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 12000/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 16000 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 16000/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 16000 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 16000/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 22050 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 22050/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 22050 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 22050/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 24000 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 24000/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 24000 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 24000/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 32000 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 32000/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 32000 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 32000/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 44100 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 44100/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 44100 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 44100/2 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 48000 Hz, 1 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 48000/1 for encodings 0x77ff.
Note: output support for 48000 Hz, 2 channels: 0x77ff
Note: Want to enable format 48000/2 for encodings 0x77ff.

Audio driver: alsa
Audio device: (null)
Audio capabilities:
(matrix of [S]tereo or [M]ono support for sample format and rate in Hz)
       |   s16 |   u16 |   s32 |   u32 |   s24 |   u24 |   f32 |    s8 |    u8 |  ulaw |  alaw |
 ------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  8000 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 11025 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 12000 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 16000 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 22050 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 24000 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 32000 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 44100 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |
 48000 |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |  M/S  |



Terminal control enabled, press 'h' for listing of keys and functions.

Playing MPEG stream 1 of 1: ocean.mpg ...
Note: Junk at the beginning (0x000001b3)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfb800000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b04bff)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b04bff)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xfa5800d7)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf4b001af)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xffe01800)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf3418000)
Note: Junk at the beginning (0xf662680c)
[src/libmpg123/parse.c:1204] error: Giving up searching valid MPEG header after 65536 bytes of junk.

[0:01] Decoding of ocean.mpg finished.
```

Comment: run with 3x `-vvv` and post the log?

Comment: voted to close this question as "belongs on superuser.com not stackoverflow.com", i'm not 100% confident, but this seems more like a superuser problem than a stackoverflow problem (have no strong feelings about it either way tho, if i'm right, i guess other people will close-vote as well)

Comment: @hanshenrik I did include the verbose output of the command

Comment: well the problem is that you're trying to run a mpg file lacking an audio track through mpg123 which only supports audio. and that mpg123 does not have a good error message for `this mpg file does not contain any audio!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... that video has a very misleading filename, it has no audio. try a file which actually contains audio, like

```
wget "https://images.wikia.com/monchbox/images/0/01/Beep-sound.ogg"
ffmpeg -i Beep-sound.ogg beep.mpg
mpg123 beep.mpg
```

... if you can be arsed, would be nice if you could complain to the filesamples.com sysadmin about the misleading filename, and the mpg123 developers about the shitty error message presented when the mpg file doesn't contain audio :o

Comment: I’m looking to display a video. Sound is therefore optional. However I might try your approach and report back

Comment: @Besi ohh i didn't catch that you actually wanted to play a video, i thought you only wanted to play the audio from a video.. mpg123 is purely an audio player, it doesn't play videos at all, which leads to mpg123's issue here: the video doesn't contain any audio